# How to handle a warrior caste?

Tags: society, warfare, culture

For generations, a hundred petty kingdoms have been in a state of constant war. This has led to the emergence of a warrior caste within the hundred kingdoms.  The members born into this caste are trained to fight since birth and have few other skills. Advancement within the caste comes only by doing great deeds on the battlefield.

A dark threat rose up to destroy the hundred kingdoms, but fortunately the chosen one emerged to unite the kingdoms into a single Empire. Now the dark threat has been destroyed and our hero must ensure that this unity continues.  To do that, he must do something with the warrior caste,  or they may once again start fighting among themselves.  Is there there a logical solution to this problem?

Comment: Hi @Bryan McClure, I made some edits to your post for grammar and clarity. Check it over and make sure I didn't change anything vital on accident.

Comment: This question is currently being voted on to be closed because it is very broad. (People really need to start stating why they flag things when doing so...) Can you edit your question to maybe limit the realm of possible answers? What kind of answers are you looking for?

Comment: Is this caste loyal to its rulers, like Ottoman Janissaries or Japanese Samurai, or they are chaotic and start wars on their own?

Comment: I need to VTC. This question has potential, but we know nothing about what's going on or why. You need to help us understand why this is not an [element of plot](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), which is listed as off-topic in the [help]. What are the politics of the kingdom? What is the perceived threat to the public? Why is fighting among themselves a problem for unity? What rules of your world are in play? What religions exist? Data!  This question needs a ton of data. Remember we're here to help you develop consistent rules for your world, not help you write a story.

Comment: And above all, by what rules or guidelines will you judge the best answer?

Comment: How many? What portion of the total population? How many were there before, how many are left after. Dealing with the 1,000 survivors of an army of 10,000 from a population of 100,000 is very different to dealing with the 500,000 survivors of an army of 2,000,000 from a population of 5,000,000

Comment: turn them into a police caste. Similar to what R. Jordan did with one of the many groups in his Wheel of Time series.

Comment: Robert Jordan addresses this in his Wheel of Time books. You turn them into the neutral third party with authority to enforce the peace.

Answer (score 5):

The most obvious answer would be to have the many kingdoms remain a Empire. They have already united so with your hero as the leader it would now be possible to either convince everyone the benefits of an empire or force them to via your hero and his army. Your warrior caste would simply become your army and maybe a police force to ensure that peace is maintained and you are protected from outside threats.

If they were to break apart into different kingdoms again they end up risking the same problem. It would be possible to setup a EU like organisation between the different kingdoms to get them to agree and policies and stop attacking each other.

Answer (score 4):

**Make them the new ruling class**. Because that'll probably happen anyways. If they have a monopoly on force and just finished saving the world, they most likely have the support of the plebes. Then they'll get fat and lazy.

**Make Ceremonial  Wars** Each municipality trains a force that competes using nonlethal methods, counting coup against other municipalities. Have a championship each year.

**Kill them all** The dark threat has been eliminated and peace established. But what if the threat has just moved on to the next world? They'll need an army there, so ritual suicide it is. Good job guys, your sacrifice is appreciated!

Comment: "*Make Ceremonial Wars*" jousting tournaments...

Comment: I was thinking the NFL.

Comment: I considered that too, but while we *call* it combat, it's nowhere near actual combat.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flower_war also springs to mind.

Comment: This is an interesting quote: "During the Spanish conquest of the Aztec Empire, Tlaxcala allied with the Spaniards against the Aztecs, **being eager to see their longtime flower war enemies overthrown**."

Answer (score 3):

As the story goes, Shaolin Kung-Fu arose from warriors who came back from war and joined the monasteries.  The Abbots forbid them from practicing their warlike ways directly, so they refined them into martial arts which could provide value in peace.

Truthfully, the answer depends *greatly* on the specifics of the warrior castes and their ethos.  What you need to find is something which can be kept alive in peace which lets that ethos continue.

In my opinion, the ultimate example of this is the guard of the [Tomb of the Unknown Soldier](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MgoZWQ1opDE).  What those soldiers do has nothing to do with fighting, and everything to do with fighting.  The spirit behind their rituals is so strong that, despite not having a single blatantly combat-oriented element to them, you can see every single shred of what makes them a soldier in every step they take.

Comment: Wasn't it developed to circumvent the prohibition of carrying weapons?

Comment: @L.Dutch The version I have been told was that the abbots were the ones who prohibited the weapons.  However, you do encourage me to go question the version I was told and do some research.

Comment: You might be a martial artist if you believe the one armed monk story ... wait ... You might be a martial artist if you know the one armed monk story.  The different apparently contradictory accounts are not necessarily mutually exclusive. China went through many phases, so it is reasonable that each story is part of the entire truth, at different times in the development of the art.

Answer (score 3):

Redefine the "battlefields" where promotions can be earned. They are now any situation where the warrior confronts danger and fights to save another human, or to save the community at large. Valor is given according to personal risk and difficulty.

- Apprehending violent criminals.
- Dispersing riots.
- Jumping into a river to save a drowning man.

Do you remember the catchword [one riot, one ranger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_Ranger_Division#%22One_Riot,_One_Ranger%22)? Well, if you reach that level you're a "general" of the warrior caste.

Comment: The question says that combat is their only skillset. Depending on how broadly that's defined ("killing things", plus what else?), it's not likely to be useful in non-violent situations, regardless of how you might redefine "battlefields". They could certainly _hunt down and kill_ violent criminals, but soldiering and police work are two distinct skill sets, and attempts to combine them into one tend to turn out badly. There's a reason why martial law has a bad reputation.

Comment: @DaveSherohman, modern-day soldiers are required to work with complex rules of engagement. Are these warriors *smart* fighters or *stupid* fighters?

Answer (score 1):

Is there a world beyond the hundred kingdoms? Start world conquest. That's how surplus of able-bodied men was traditionally utilized in history.

If world conquest is not really desired, engineer a mechanism so fallen members of warrior caste are not easily replaced. The conquest would stall, and less numerous warriors would not threat the integrity of the empire.

Answer (score 1):

*Fake News*

Somehow convince them using propaganda that the dark threat isn't really gone.

*Drugs*

Make some non lethal but addictive drugs legal. So that they just sleep and lose warlike tendencies.

*Education*

Make schools so hard and prestigious that the warriors can't find time to exercise. Also, their children can be programmed in schools to your requirements.

*Diet*

Tell them what they have been eating for generations is unhealthy and introduce lots of crazy diet ideas to keep them confused.

And other such tricks. You get the picture I hope. :-)

Note: I should stop reading dystopian novels. Lol.